# How to customize the background color of a editingAccessoryView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I using `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`
to display Edit button, the edit button show with white background.
how can I set the background to another color ?

I tried:

```
    cell.editingAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

not work, any idea ?

Comment: Show how you create and assign the `editingAccessoryView` for your cell.

Comment: I didn't create more than "[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];"

Comment: If you aren't setting your own `editingAccessoryView` then why are you trying to set the background color of a non-existent view?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean, meanwhile I added only the line "[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];" which shows the edit button.

Comment: I mean just what I said. There is no point to setting the background of `editingAccessoryView` since you are not making use of the cell's `editingAccessoryView`.